# width and swap for SlideJS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a simple site to learn Twitter Bootstrap and SlideJS. The below code is what I have so far. I currently have two problems. The first is that even though I have swap set to false it still shows PlayStop at the bottom of the slider. My second problem is that no matter what I do every time I put something in a div with a class container(twitter bootstrap class) I am unable to resize the width of anything within the container they all just take the entire width of the container.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            #slides{
                display: none;

            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">


            $(function(){
              $("#slides").slidesjs({
                width: 700,
                height: 393,
                navigation: {active: false, effect: "fade"},
                pagination: {active: false},

                play: {
                    active: true,
                    effect: "fade",
                    interval: 4500,
                    auto: true,
                    swap: false,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    restartDelay: 2500
                }
              });

            });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
           <div id="slides">

                <img src="imgs/alfa1.jpg" width="600" height="400"/>

                <img src="imgs/alfa2.jpg" width="600" height="400"/>

                <img src="imgs/alfa3.jpg" width="600" height="400"/>

                <img src="imgs/alfa4.jpg" width="600" height="400"/>

                <img src="imgs/alfa5.jpg" width="600" height="400"/>

                <img src="imgs/alfa6.jpg" width="600" height="400"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. what swap does is display play OR stop instead of play AND stop. If you want to disable the menu, set `play : { active: false };`
2. I'm not sure what you mean on by resize the child width? I have made a working example on jsfiddle (it would help in the future to present your question in a sandbox like jsfiddle). If you could clarify the question, I would be glad to help.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/mAWLM/

Comment: Well it's because it's in a container dive with a container class from twitter bootstrap. I'm trying to figure out how to fix that. The first solution you gave me worked by the way thanks.